# Сортировка по полю массива различных объектов IComparable

Tags: c#

Я попытался разобраться с сортировкой массива объектов при помощи интерфейса IComparable. Увы не понял, как верно реализовать. Создал самый простой, как мне показалось пример:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person[] p = new Person[5];
            p[0] = new Driver("Shumaher","Driver_F1");
            p[1] = new Waiter("Valera","Kapitan");
            p[2] = new Sailor("Vasia","Soldier",3);
            p[3] = new Waiter("Sasha","Senior");
            p[4] = new Sailor("Greg","Cook",1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Person:IComparable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
    public class Driver:Person
    {
        private string Who { get; set; }

        public Driver(string name,string who)
        {
            base.Name = name;
            Who = who;
        }
    }
    public class Waiter : Person
    {
        private string who;

        public Waiter(string name,string who)
        {
            base.Name = name;
            this.who = who;
        }

    }
    public class Sailor : Person
    {
        private string who;
        private int how_long;
        public Sailor(string name,string who,int how_long)
        {
            base.Name = name;
            this.who = who;
            this.how_long = how_long;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот есть общее поле, как отсортировать то.... Помогите разобраться

Comment: CompareTo не реализован

Comment: @Valera Kvip, смотрите, CompareTo(если я не ошибаюсь) сравнивает два объекта, а как сделать, что бы он сравнивал поля? И не по длине а по первой букве поля.... Что-то у меня с переопределением этого метода вообще беда.

Answer (score 3):

Должно быть как-то так:

```
public class Person: IComparable<Person>, IComparable
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int CompareTo(Person other)
  {
    return other?.Name?.CompareTo(this.Name) ?? -1;
  }

  int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
  {
    return this.CompareTo(obj as Person);
  }
}
```

Comment: эм, вы меня очень озадачили, а как это вызвать?(

Comment: @Valera Ну раз я не успел дописать ответ, то хоть в комментариях подскажу. Сортировкой массива `Array.Sort(p);` Рекомендую к прочтению так же https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.23.php.

Comment: @AlexKrass, ну почему ж не успел? Дописывай уж)

Comment: @Valera, а зачем это вызывать? Ты же сам писал про стандартную сортировку массивов - он там внутри вызовет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да все равно тоже самое получилось практически... p.s. linq портит людей: `p = p.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToArray();`.

Comment: @AlexKrass, так ведь linq гибче и удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный интерфейс выглядит следующим образом:

```
public interface IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(object o);
}
```

Метод `CompareTo` сравнивает текущий объект с объектом переданным в качестве параметра и возвращает целое число, которое может иметь одно из трех значений:

1. меньше нуля - текущий объект должен находиться выше (перед) переданным
2. равен нулю - оба объекта равны
3. больше нуля - текущий объект должен находиться ниже (после) переданного

---

К примеру сортировка может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
public class Person : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object person)
    {
        //здесь пишем сравнение
        Person p = person as Person;

        if (p == null) throw new InvalidCastException();

        if (Name.First() > p.Name.First()) return 1;
        else if (Name.First() == p.Name.First()) return 0;
        else return -1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person[] p = new Person[5];
        p[0] = new Driver("Shumaher", "Driver_F1");
        p[1] = new Waiter("Valera", "Kapitan");
        p[2] = new Sailor("Vasia", "Soldier", 3);
        p[3] = new Waiter("Sasha", "Senior");
        p[4] = new Sailor("Greg", "Cook", 1);

        Array.Sort(p);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

Так же можно воспользоваться обобщенным интерфейсом `public interface IComparable<in T>` и стандартной сортировкой для строк, в итоге получив следующее.

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person person)
    {
        return Name.CompareTo(person.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё очень хорошо расписано, большое спасибо. Только я не понимаю, как связан Array.Sort c compareTo. Как это происходит, может я очень тупой, но как...))??

Comment: @Valera внутри он вызывает метод `CompareTo` у объекта и смотрит, какой знак он вернул. Тоже самое будет с коллекциями `List<T>.Sort()` или LINQ методом `OrderBy(p => p)`. Внутри себя они вызывают метод `CompareTo` и ориентируются на знак числа, который он вернул. Можно для практики даже написать свою пузырьковую сортировку массива, ориентируясь только на метод `CompareTo`: `if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[i+1]) > 0) swap(a, b);`. Будет вполне наглядно демонстрировать работу этого интерфейса.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, когда я вызываю Array.Sort(s) сортировка производится согласно определенному методу CompareTo?

Comment: @Valera сортировка определяет порядок элементов согласно методу CompareTo. Если вы это имели ввиду, то да, сортировка использует его.

Comment: Дада, спасибо большое!!